# Why does $\phi_*[X,Y]=[\phi_*X,\phi_*Y]$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, continuous-homomorphisms

I am a high schooler self-studying differential geometry. I am stuck trying to show the following:

Let $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ be a diffeomorphism, and $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields on $M$. Show that $\phi_*[X,Y]=[\phi_*X,\phi_*Y]$.

I want to still solve the problem by myself, and I have played around with different definitions of the push forward and commutator, but I have been unable to show the property holds. Could I have a sketch of the proof / some pointers on good directions to head in order to show it? The main thing I’ve tried doing is rewriting $(\phi_*)X_{\phi(p)}=(D_p\phi)X_p$, but I am unsure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

**We first prove that**
$$X(f\circ\phi)=((\phi_*X)f)\circ\phi.$$
On one hand,
$$(\phi_*X)_{\phi(p)}f=(D_p\phi)X_pf=X_p(f\circ\phi)=X(f\circ\phi)(p).$$
On the other hand,
$$(\phi_*X)_{\phi(p)}f=((\phi_*X)f)\circ\phi(p).$$
Thus
$$X(f\circ\phi)(p)=((\phi_*X)f)\circ\phi(p).$$
**Now we prove the desired result**
$$\phi_*[X,Y]=[\phi_*X,\phi_*Y].$$
Note that
$$XY(f\circ\phi)=X(((\phi_*Y)f)\circ\phi)=((\phi_*X\phi_*Y)f)\circ\phi.$$
Similarly,
$$YX(f\circ\phi)=((\phi_*Y\phi_*X)f)\circ\phi.$$
Therefore
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}\phi_*[X,Y]f&=[X,Y](f\circ\phi)\\
   &=XY(f\circ\phi)-YX(f\circ\phi)\\
   &=((\phi_*X\phi_*Y)f)\circ\phi-((\phi_*Y\phi_*X)f)\circ\phi\\
   &=([\phi_*X,\phi_*Y]f)\circ\phi.
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: It was a duplicate (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cphi_*%5BX%2CY%5D%3D%5B%5Cphi_*X%2C%5Cphi_*Y%5D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aproof&p=1)).